# What's the application-context-id in Facebook Graph and how do I get it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native

### Application Context Friends Using App

I am trying to get friends of a user using the app with [friends_using_app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application-context/friends_using_app/) node.

However, I don't know how get to the `{application-context-id}`. I am testing the endpoint using the Facebook Graph API explorer.

Also, I am using react-native-fbsk.

Comment: Whenever I try it using the app-id I get this error.

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (friends_using_app) on node type (Application)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AV99aREyTLM"
  }
}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UPDATE: Ignore the screenshot, answer is in the comments.

I think they're talking about your App ID, which you can get [by following these instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register/). Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It's not the app-id, I tried it already. You can also try it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Looking around, it seems like you'll probably get the application-context-id from the response based on this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551737/getting-the-user-context-id-for-a-facebook-open-graph-api-query. Though it concerns user-context-id, I think they're probably using a similar convention.

Comment: @ViktorLeNerd You can consider unaccepting this answer

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/app.context/friends_using_app

The request to get the application context for an app is

```
GET /v2.10/{app-id}?fields=context
```

There don't currently seem to be any other contexts, so don't need to ask for the sub-field `friends_using_app` specifically (although you could.)

You'll see it returns the list of friends directly, but also an `id` - that is the application context id you could use for the request `GET /v2.10/{application-context-id}/friends_using_app` - but since above request returns the data already, that seems to be unnecessary.

You need to make this request with a user access token that includes `user_friends` permission, and it will only surface friends that have also granted `user_friends` permission to the app on their end. Therefor, **the result is the same, as if we had simply requested `/me/friends` in the first place**, so I actually don't see the point of that application context ... maybe it was added for "completeness" sake, because there's other types of data that you would request in a similar way, I don't know ...